# How to draw vertical line and horizontal markers

Tags: html, css

How can I make a vertical line and horizontal markers (an `L` shape) using CSS:

something like:

```
Test 
  L  T2
  L  t3
```

Comment: What's your current HTML/CSS?

Comment: You mean like for a folder/file explorer?

Comment: Yeah... not really sure what is being asked here.

Comment: Are you looking for └? Probably not but your question is extremely vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `div` for this, because you have pseudo-elements!  Here's a quick example I threw together, and you can find a working sample here: http://jsbin.com/aladez/2

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Herp</li>
    <li>Derp</li>
    <li>Derp</li>
 </ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    list-style: none; 
}

li:before {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
    font-size: 4px;
    line-height: 4px;
    padding: 4px 8px 0 0;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: @joe: Not really. There's no way to use `:before` from an inline style. Though you can do this if you *really want to*: http://jsbin.com/aladez/3. But, please don't.

Comment: @joe - No, you can't use pseudo-elements inline. However, you should definitely avoid inline styles.  Use external stylesheets and your site will be much easier to maintain.

Comment: @joe - IE 7 and below, yes, it doesn't work. However, is this tiny bit of list styling worth the extra markup to support it? How many visitors will be using IE 7? How important is this style to the overall experience of your site?  Will visitors in older browsers even notice?  My guess is that it's not worth it, but these are the things you should consider for any feature that affects older browsers.  I don't have a right answer for that; it's between you, your customers, and your users.

Answer (score 1):

Create a div with the following css:

```
width: 20px; //or whatever width you want for the horizontal line
height: 40px; //or whatever height you want for the vertical line
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
border-left: 1px solid black;
```

and plant it where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could add a `div` and set the border as `div { border-left: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid; }`. Adjust width and height of that div till it fits your needs. You would also want to make sure that you set `float: left` for the div.

I don't think there is a solution in html which works OOTB.